# Use of "its" in place of his or her

Tags: pronouns

I've come across the following sentence where "its" is used, instead of using his/her:

> Unless a parent can keep up with **its** children, its fate is sealed." [example from [Longman Dictionary of
>   Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/keep-up-with)].

The question is: why do we use its here instead of his or her? Isn't a parent an animated object?

Comment: Yes, that's very peculiar. Could you please tell us more about where you found that example?

Comment: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/keep-up-with @tchrist Thanks for your respond so fast, here is the link where i found that

Comment: Thanks. I can't explain it. That's certainly ungrammatical to me.

Comment: For explanation, we would need a context.  In Longman, it is merely an "example from the corpus".

Comment: I would have written _Unless a parent can keep up with their children_ using the singularised, genderless pronoun.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this example came from something like [THIS](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch14_07.htm), talking about computer networking or routing.  There are things called "zones" which may be related to each other as "parent" and "child"...

> The first (and simplest) case occurs if a parent zone doesn't keep up with its children or if the children don't inform the parent of changes to the authoritative name servers for the zone.